# SQL: Can't Insert Image into Image column

Tags: sql

I'm trying to insert a image into a column. currently its in binary form. The issue is it wants to add 0x03c and it should be 0x3c. So it keeps adding stuff to the binary. Not sure how to stop this from happening.

Query:

```
    INSERT INTO [Collage].[dbo].[Summary]
([DataSet], [LastUpdate], [Data])
VALUES(
'Statistics',
'2019-10-03 21:40:20.200',
0x3C537461)
```

Result:

```
0x03C537461
```

As you can see the binary is not correct. I reduced the size of the array because its huge but you get the idea.

Comment: what SQL engine? how is the column configured?

Comment: According to your own code snippet, you are getting back exactly what you are inserting.

Comment: notice the 0x3 vs 0x03 Thats the difference

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017